# Отказано в доступе к папке

Tags: c#

Как дать доступ приложению к папке?

[image]

```
        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        string m = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        marks.Add(m);
        using (var fs = new FileStream("c:\\temp.xml", FileMode.Create))
        new XmlSerializer(marks.GetType()).Serialize(fs, marks);
```

Comment: Запустить от админа? C - системный диск. Ну а вообще используйте для этого специальные директории.

Comment: Код какой-то бредовый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В современных версиях Windows нельзя писать файлы в корень системного диска без админских прав.

Comment: Если диск единственный, то всегда можно писать в `"%USERPROFILE%"` чтобы не создавать папочки и не привязываться к путям.

Comment: Тогда правильней в AppData писать, там же и временная папка пользователя находится `AppData\Local\Temp`, которая имеет алиас `%Temp%`